# subscript out of bounds R for large for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, permutation, statistical-test

I have a for loop which works perfectly for (relative) small amount of repetitions times=10,100.  But for larger values for "times" I get an error by filling-in the matrix: subscript out of bounds... (See code below, and code-explanation)

Error:
`Error in M_zp_var[j, (1:n)] : subscript out of bounds`

To fill the matrix I use a second for-loop in the first one

```
M_zp<-matrix(numeric(1),B,N)
for(j in 1:dim(M_zp)[1]){ M_zp[j,]<-Z_pi(x,y) }
```

and I even tried it with

```
M_zp<-t(replicate(B, Z_pi(x,y)))
```

instead, but it does not work either.

As I said the code works if my outer-for-loop is small. I do not understand why should it work differently if I choose the variable "times" larger (1000, 5000).

I know the meaning of "subscript out of bounds"

I hope you can help me I would be so greatfull! :(

Code:

```
T_p<- matrix(numeric(1),times,Bvar)
  H0 <- numeric(times)
  for(i in 1:times){
    # Each loop starts with a new random vector
    x<-rnorm(n)   #x<- rdist(n,...); #
y<-rnorm(m)   #y<- rdist(m,...); #

# Order statstic with T_pi's T(Z(pi))
n<-length(x)
m<-length(y)
N<-n+m

#Permutate (x,y) B times
**M_zp<-matrix(numeric(1),B,N)
for(j in 1:dim(M_zp)[1]){ M_zp[j,]<-Z_pi(x,y) }** #see below for Z_pi() funct.
#M_zp<-t(replicate(B, Z_pi(x,y)))
M_zp_var<-unique(M_zp)
Bf<-dim(unique(M_zp))[1]

#Test statistic computation for each one of the Permutations in M_zp_var
T_pvec<-numeric(Bvar)
for(j in 1:Bvar){
  xp<-M_zp_var[j,(1:n)]
  yp<-M_zp_var[j,((n+1):(n+m))]
  m_xp<- mstern(xp) 
  m_yp<- mstern(yp) 
  T_pvec[j]<-(sd(xp)-sd(yp))/sqrt(m_xp/n+m_yp/m)
}
T_p[i,]<-sort(T_pvec)
}


Z_pi<-function(x,y){
  n<-length(x)
  m<-length(y)
  x<-sort(x)
  y<-sort(y)
  wicy<-function(s){ wi<-which(y==s); return(wi)}
  wicx<-function(s){ wi<-which(x==s); return(wi)}
  r<-sample(1:min(n,m),1)   #interger beween 1 and min(m+n) = length of entries to interchange between x and y
  zwy<-sample(y,r)          #vector of length r out of entries in y (randomly) =intries to interchange with x
  wy<-unlist(lapply(zwy,wicy))
  zwx<-sample(x,r)
  wx<-unlist(lapply(zwx,wicx))

  yp<-y
  xp<-x
  yp[wy]<-zwx
  xp[wx]<-zwy
  zp<-c(sort(xp), sort(yp))
  return(zp)
}
```

Explanation:

The loop simulates "times"-times a permutation test (Monte-Carlo). One loop generates 2 random samples and then permutates them randomly B=16000 times (a permutation is made with the function `Z_pi()` ), then it takes only the different permuatations (`unique()` ) And out of each permutation it calculates a Test statistic... The codes stops working at the marked row (in bold) which involves the function `Z_pi()`.

Comment: Subscripts for matrices need to be integers and you should look at  .Machine["integer.max"]. You should also consider using `browser()` as your error recovery option so you can examine the offending index when the error is thrown. See `?options`

Comment: Are you sure it is not a simple typing error? You determine the number of rows in M_zp_var as Bf, but you loop over Bvar. Shouldn't that be Bf? Now you have the risk that Bvar is larger than Bf. If this is unlikely, it will only appear when you do many iterations